# Error no Jest: This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I'm trying to run Jest with React, I started the project with --create-react-app, then added --babel and after --jest, but when I run [yarn jest], this error is displayed on screen, can anyone help me?

This is the error:

```
 FAIL  src/pages/users/__tests__/add.test.js
 Test suite failed to run

Jest encountered an unexpected token

This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

Here's what you can do:
 • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
 • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
 • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html

Details:

SyntaxError: /usr/lib/myProjects/tryning/src/pages/users/add/index.js: Unexpected token (124:8)

  122 | 
  123 |     return (
> 124 |         <>
      |         ^
  125 |             <Top />
  126 |             <Menu />
  127 |             <div className="user-add-form">

  at Parser.raise (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/location.js:41:63)
  at Parser.unexpected (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/util.js:160:16)
  at Parser.parseExprAtom (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:1143:20)
  at Parser.parseExprSubscripts (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:553:23)
  at Parser.parseMaybeUnary (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:533:21)
  at Parser.parseExprOps (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:301:23)
  at Parser.parseMaybeConditional (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:256:23)
  at Parser.parseMaybeAssign (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:186:21)
  at Parser.parseParenAndDistinguishExpression (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:1312:16)
  at Parser.parseExprAtom (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:1050:21)

  Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
  Tests:       0 total
  Snapshots:   0 total
  Time:        4.267s
  Ran all test suites.
  error Command failed with exit code 1.
  info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

This is file test:

```
import React from 'react';

import Enzyme, { mount } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
const addUser = require('../add/index');

describe('MyComponent', () => {
    it('works', () => {
        expect(addUser.fieldCheck('Nelson')).to(true);
    });
});
```

This is the file I am trying to test:

```
      import React, { useState } from 'react';
      import './style.css';
      import Menu from '../../../components/menu';
      import Top from '../../../components/top';
      import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

    const AddUser = () => {

    const [nameInput, setName] = useState('');
    const [cpfInput, setCpf] = useState('');
    const [userInput, setUser] = useState('');
    const [passInput, setPass] = useState('');

    let accounts = [];

    var accountsJson = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tableUser'));

    const fieldCheck = field => {
        if (field.value === null || field.value.trim() === ""){
            field.style = "border: 1px solid #ff0000";
            return false;
        }
        else{
            field.style = "border: 1px solid #339680";
            return true;
        }
    }

    const account = {
        name: '',
        cpf: '',
        user: '',
        pass: '',
    };

    const finalWarning = (operation, error) => {
        switch (operation) {
            case 'save':
                return 'Save with sucess!';
            case 'error':
                return 'An error has occurred: '
                    .concat(error)
                    .concat("!");
            case 'cancel':
                return 'The action has been undone!';
            case 'empty':
                return 'Fields on red not can are empty!'

            default:
                return 'Do not possible return in [finalWarning] >52';
        }
    }

    const confirmSave = () => {
        var op = window.confirm("Are you sure you want to save?");
        return op;
    }

    const cleanFields = () => {
        setName('');
        setCpf('');
        setUser('');
        setPass('');
    }

    const emptyFields = inputsElements => {
        var haveEmpty = false;
        inputsElements.map(input => {
            if (document.getElementsByName(input)[0].value === "") {
                document.getElementsByName(input)[0].style = "border: 1px solid #ff0000";
                haveEmpty = true;
            }
            else {
                haveEmpty = false;
            }
        });
        if (haveEmpty) {
            alert(finalWarning('empty'));
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    const addAccount = account => {
        accounts.push(account);
        localStorage.setItem('tableUser', JSON.stringify(accounts));
    }

    const handleFormSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault();

        account.name = nameInput;
        account.cpf = cpfInput;
        account.user = userInput;
        account.pass = passInput;

        if (!emptyFields(['nameInput', 'cpfInput', 'userInput', 'passInput'])) {
            if (confirmSave())
                try {
                    accounts = [];
                    for (var i in accountsJson)
                        accounts.push(accountsJson[i]);

                    addAccount(account);

                    cleanFields();

                    alert(finalWarning('save'));
                    window.location.href = "/users";
                }
                catch (e) {
                    alert(finalWarning('error', e));
                    alert(e);
                    window.location.href = "/users";
                }
            else
                alert(finalWarning('cancel'));
        }
    }

    return (
        <>
            <Top />
            <Menu />
            <div className="user-add-form">
                <div className="line-top"></div>
                <form method="post" id="user-add-form" onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}>
                    <div className="user-add-fields">
                        Name
                    <input
                            onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)}
                            name="nameInput"
                            value={nameInput}
                            type="text"
                            placeholder="Insert name."
                            onBlur={e => fieldCheck(e.target)}
                        />
                        CPF
                    <input
                            onChange={e => setCpf(e.target.value)}
                            name="cpfInput"
                            value={cpfInput}
                            type="text"
                            placeholder="Insert cpf."
                            onBlur={e => fieldCheck(e.target)}
                        />
                        User
                    <input
                            onChange={e => setUser(e.target.value)}
                            name="userInput"
                            value={userInput}
                            type="text"
                            placeholder="Insert user."
                            onBlur={e => fieldCheck(e.target)}

                        />
                        Password
                    <input
                            onChange={e => setPass(e.target.value)}
                            name="passInput"
                            value={passInput}
                            type="password"
                            placeholder="Insert password."
                            onBlur={e => fieldCheck(e.target)}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <button
                        type="submit"
                        className=" button user-add-save-button"
                    >
                        Save
                    </button>
                </form>
                <Link to="/Users" className="button user-add-cancel-button" >
                    Cancel
                </Link>
            </div >
        </>
    );
}

export default AddUser;
```

This is my file package.json:

```
{
  "name": "trying",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.3",
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.10.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.1",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.2.0",
    "tab": "^1.0.0",
    "tabs": "^0.2.0",
    "webfontloader": "^1.6.28"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "jest",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

This is my Babel.js:

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"],
    "plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-async-to-generator"
    ]
}
```

Follow the project link on Github to:
[User Registration Github](https://github.com/nelsonanjos/userRegistration)

Comment: Could we also see your test file code?

Comment: Yes, indeed, I had forgotten. I will edit the post. Thank you.

Comment: install [babel-jest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-jest) package

Comment: Hello i installed babel-jest, but still the same error remains.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys, besides having to install **babel-jest**, I had to do some configurations before.

1st. I executed the command

> npm run eject

in the project;

2nd In the "packge.json" file, I changed "testMatch" to find the test folder, which I created in the project root;

3rd I created an adapter file to run before the test:

```
//<rootDir>/__tests__/setup.js
import Enzyme from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

Enzyme.configure ({adapter: new Adapter ()});
```

4th Add the libraries:

> enzyme enzyme-adapter-react-16 react-test-render

`

Then it worked.